# Executing parallel tasks -> wait for all -> make use of result

Tags: c#, asp.net

`GetSystems()` and `GetActions()` both returns `IEnumerable<T>` of different types. What do I need to do to access the results below? Do I need to make use of `Task.WaitAll()` or something similar?

```
Task t1 = new Task(() => GetSystems());
Task t2 = new Task(() => GetActions());

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>() { t1, t2 };

Parallel.ForEach(tasks, t =>
                          {
                              t.Start();
                          });

//t1.Result...?
```

I'm using C# 4.0.

Update:

```
private Task<List<SYSTEM>> GetSystems()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            return context.SYSTEM.ToList();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `Task` doesn't have a `Result` property. `Task<T>` does. We don't know what `GetSystems` or `GetActions` do, but you almost certainly want a `Task<T>` of some form.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right, I've updated with one of the methods in its current state. Would you mind showing me how to make it return the desired type?

Comment: Well it sounds like you want `Task<IEnumerable<AS_SYSTEM>>` t1 = new Task(() => GetSystems());`. However, you almost certainly want to return `context.SYSTEM.ToList()` otherwise it won't be useful for you...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, do you have any objections on my updated code snippet?

Comment: @JonSkeet Allright, thank you. Please post it as an answer so that I can give you the rep :)

Comment: It's not clear to me that that's answered your actual question, but hey...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Task<T>` in order to use the `Result` property. Given the comments, it looks like you want:

```
Task<List<SYSTEM>> t1 = ...;
Task<List<ACTION>> t2 = ...;

Task[] tasks = { t1, t2 };

Parallel.ForEach(tasks, t => t.Start());

Task.WaitAll(tasks);

List<SYSTEM> systems = t1.Result;
List<ACTION> actions = t2.Result;
```

You should consider how you'll handle failure cases though.

Comment: then do a `tasks.ToArray()` :)